# unable to access json response in postman pre requisite script

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

In pre requesite script ,send a request and it is giving 200 status code and res.json() used but it is showing undefined

I tried var r =res.json()
console.log(r) but it is giving undefined

Comment: Please post the code used to get the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a response in a pre-request script (it is executed before the request is sent), you need to use the tests tab:

```
var j = pm.response.json();
console.log(j);
```